# The ListView updates the value of the wrong line

Tags: android, android-listview, xamarin, xamarin.android, baseadapter

In the code below I have a ListView with a Items list containing Name, Id and Quantity. When I click on a row this value should be updated according to informed parameter in UpdateItemSelectedInListView () method. But only line 9 is having the changed value, independent of the line that I select.

Activity:

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    ListView    _ListView;

    AdapterItem _Adapter;

    List<Item> _ListaItem = new List<Item>();

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        CriaListView();
    }

    private void CriaListView()
    {
        _ListView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listaItems);

        _ListView.ItemClick += _ListView_ItemClick;

        _ListView.Adapter = CriaAdapter();
    }

    private AdapterItem CriaAdapter()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        {
            _ListaItem.Add(new Item("Test Name",i));  
        }

        _Adapter = new AdapterItem(this, _ListaItem);

        return _Adapter;
    }
    void _ListView_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        _Adapter.UpdateItemSelectedInListView(e.Position, 5);
    }
}
```

Adapter:

```
public class AdapterItem : BaseAdapter
{

List<Item>     _ListaItem = new List<Item>();

Activity       _Activity;

LayoutInflater _Inflate;

ViewHolderItem _HolderItem;

Boolean        _HasUpdate;

int            _IdToUpDate;

int            _NewQntd;

int            _Position;

public AdapterItem(Activity activity, List<Item> listaItem)
{
    _Activity = activity;

    _ListaItem = listaItem;

    try
    {
        _Inflate = (LayoutInflater)_Activity.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
}

View _View;

public override View GetView(int position, Android.Views.View convertView,  Android.Views.ViewGroup parent)
{
    _View = convertView;

    try
    {
        if (_View != null)
            _HolderItem = _View.Tag as ViewHolderItem;

        else
        {
            _View = _Activity.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.LayoutItem, null);

            _HolderItem = CriaViewHolder();
        }

        PopulaViewHolder(position);

        _View.Tag = _HolderItem;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }

    return _View;
}

private ViewHolderItem CriaViewHolder()
{
    ViewHolderItem holderItem = new ViewHolderItem();

    holderItem.txtNameItem = _View.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.nameItem);

    holderItem.txtIdItem   = _View.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.idItem);

    holderItem.txtqntItem  = _View.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.totalInStock);

    return holderItem;
}

private void PopulaViewHolder(int position)
{
    _HolderItem.txtNameItem.Text = _ListaItem[position].nome;

    _HolderItem.txtIdItem.Text   = _ListaItem[position].id.ToString();

    if (_HasUpdate && (position == _Position)) 
        UpdateAdapter();
}

public void UpdateAdapter()
{
    _HolderItem.txtqntItem.Text = _NewQntd.ToString();

    _HasUpdate = false;
}

public void UpdateItemSelectedInListView(int position, int newValue)
{
    _NewQntd = newValue;

    _HasUpdate = true;

    _Position = position;

    this.NotifyDataSetChanged();
}

public override Java.Lang.Object GetItem(int position)
{
    return 0;
}

public override int Count
{
    get {return _ListaItem.Count; }
}

public override long GetItemId(int position)
{
    return _ListaItem[position].id;
}

public override int GetItemViewType(int position)
{
    return base.GetItemViewType(position);
}

public override int ViewTypeCount
{
    get
    {
        return base.ViewTypeCount;
    }
}

private class ViewHolderItem : Java.Lang.Object
{
    public TextView txtNameItem { get; set; }
    public TextView txtIdItem   { get; set; }
    public TextView txtqntItem  { get; set; }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to move `_View.Tag = _HolderItem;` inside of the else on the `GetView` method:

```
public override View GetView(int position, Android.Views.View convertView, Android.Views.ViewGroup parent)
{
    _View = convertView;

    try
    {
        if (_View != null)
            _HolderItem = _View.Tag as ViewHolderItem;

        else
        {
            _View = _Activity.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.LayoutItem, null);

            _HolderItem = CriaViewHolder();

            //Set the tag only when you create a new one
            //otherwise you'll have the problem you are having
            _View.Tag = _HolderItem;
        }

        PopulaViewHolder(position);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }

    return _View;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your _Adapter.UpdateItemSelectedInListView not fetching correct position as it looses the state. Instead you can make use of binding "event action" to each view row from viewholder class. 
On trigger of this action event [ in GetView()] another event action to activity class to process Click event.

```
//Viewholder class      
internal Action ActionImgViewSelectedToGetView{ get; set;} 
       internal void Initialize(View view)
       {
        imgItem=view.FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.imgItem);
        imgItem.Click += delegate(object sender , EventArgs e )
        {
         ActionImgViewSelectedToGetView(); //action event to getview()
        };  
       }
```

//in getview()

```
viewHolder.ActionImgViewSelectedToGetView = () =>
  {
   if(ActionImgSelectedToActivity!=null)
    ActionImgSelectedToActivity(_lstItem[position].ItemName); //action event,targeting to activity class method
  };
```

//activity

```
if ( objItemAdapter != null )
    {
     objItemAdapter.ActionImgSelectedToActivity -= SelectedItem;
     objItemAdapter = null;
    } 
    objItemAdapter = new ItemAdapterClass (this, lstItem);
    objItemAdapter.ActionImgSelectedToActivity += SelectedItem;
    listViewItem.Adapter = objItemAdapter;

void SelectedItem( string strItemName)
        {
            //seleced item
        }
```

for more detail : http://appliedcodelog.blogspot.in/2015/07/working-on-issues-with-listview-in.html#WrongPosition